# In Mongoose, how do you find an array of objects where an object has a specific key/value?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

In the Mongoose model `Person`, there is an array of objects called `matches`.

`matches` looks like

```
     [
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b5825"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b58a0"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b58c6"
        }
    ],
```

I want to create a query that finds a `Person` who has the ID in his `matches` array.

The problem is that the query for matches only seems to work for arrays of strings, like

```
models.Person.find({matches: 558ced061d35bd072e7b58c6})
```

but not for arrays of objects that contain string values.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: have you used `$elemMatch`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the string to ObjectId and use that in your query as follows:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    person_id  = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("558ced061d35bd072e7b58c6");

models.Person.find({ "matches": person_id }).exec(callback);
```